# Customize and Optimize Linux Kernel

Tags: optimization, linux-kernel, customization

I want to optimize a Linux Kernel 4.5.2 to minimize the boot duration, have you got some ideas ?

Customization:
A splash screen that displays a picture instead of the services logs.
The possibility to choose the kernel I want to boot when I load my Linux.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to Stack Overflow! I think your question might be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. If you edited it to say what you've tried to optimise it and what effects that has had, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki [elinux.org](http://elinux.org/Boot_Time) contains a set of pages related to boot time optimization. I mentions loads of technologies and projects that can help you as well as many papers and conference presentations that show how others have successfully reduced their boot times down to far less than a second in some cases.